# VBA, For , For Each for entire range instead of each row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to put a value in each row, not the entire row. Currently now my data is putting "Failed" for the whole range when only one cell that `OK` applies to should be "Failed"

`OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(insertPoint, sourceDoc, startPage, endPage - startPage, False)`

OK will return true or false.

Tried a `For` Loop

```
 For row_num = 8 To max_row
        If OK = True Then
            Range("O8:O43").value = "Completed"
        Else
            Range("O8:O43").value = "Failed"
        End If
        Next row_num
```

Tried a `For each` loop

```
Set a = Range("O3:O43")

For Each cell In a.Rows
    If OK = True Then
        a.value = "Completed"
    Else
        a.value = "Failed"
    End If
Next
```

**Current results:**

[image]

**Expected**:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hard to help without seeing how `OK` is declared and assigned a value.

Comment: please see question.

Comment: Please edit your question to add clarification. Don't do that in a comment.

Comment: mkay, so what type is `primaryDoc` and does its `InsertPages` method return a `Boolean` value? What's supposed to make `OK` change its value inside the loop body?

Comment: `primarydoc` is a object. `InsertPages` I believe is also a object. `OK` returns true or false.

Comment: Can you please learn how to use this site and Edit your Question with clarifications. Don't put them into comments. If you have an issue with following simple rules, please, how can we help you?

Answer (score 4):

In your first code sample, you are always applying the value to all the cells. Don't do that. Only apply the value to the current cell, i.e. the one in the row of `row_num`. It will also depend on the current value of `OK`, of course. Your code does not seem to change the value of `OK` in each iteration of the loop, so it is not clear what it refers to.

```
 For row_num = 8 To max_row
        If OK = True Then
            Range("O" & row_num).value = "Completed"
        Else
            Range("O" & row_num).value = "Failed"
        End If
  Next row_num
```

Comment: I think it is the value of `OK` which is throwing me off.  The value of `OK` is either true or false.

Comment: @excelguy yes, that's what a `Boolean` value will be (you can even skip the `=True` part and do `If OK Then`) - the key of the problem is that the value of `OK` needs to be re-evaluated *at every iteration of the loop*. So whatever is assigning `OK` needs to be *inside the loop*. Likely, you could remove `OK` altogether, and do `If primaryDoc.InsertPages(insertPoint, sourceDoc, startPage, endPage - startPage, False) Then`, assuming the parameters given to `InsertPages` reflect the curent `row_num`.

Comment: I dont think `insertpages` or `OK` reflects current row_num. This could be my issue.